# Insert many documents to MongoDB didn't insert them all

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I want to add 1,000,000 documents to MongoDB.
I run this dummy code,

```
Mongo mongo = null;
mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);

DB db = mongo.getDB("MyTestDB");

System.out.println("Connection was established....");

DBCollection col = db.getCollection("ThirdCollection");

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("name", "MongoDB "+i)
            .append("type", "database")
            .append("count", 1)
            .append("info",
                    new BasicDBObject("x", 203).append("y", 102));

    col.insert(doc);
}
```

And I see that it insert only 99,637 documents.

I am new in MongoDB, maybe it is optimisation issue or something else?

Thanks

Comment: If you set full writeconcern in the Java driver does it insert the correct number of docs?

Comment: How can I change it? I dont understand, I didnt change drivers config

Comment: You can set it on the mongo object itself I believe (I am not a Java expert): `mongo = new Mongo(serverAddress); mongo.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE);`